# Getting slot filling answer in webhook as a variable

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform

I am using the Google Actions Console and trying to get the value of my slot filling. I have made two slot fillings. One is called the numerator and the other is called the denominator. They are both type actions.type.Number. After the slots are filled, I call my webhook to try to get them out.

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = conversation();

app.handle('pct_handle', conv => {
  // Implement your code here
  var numerator=session.params.numerator;
  var denominator=session.params.denominator;
  var answer=numerator/denominator;
  conv.add("Your answer is ${answer}");
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I just want to know how to call these variables I just sent from the user. More broadly if you can tell me where a reference to this object model that would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

```
app.handle('pct_handle', conv => {


// Implement your code here
  var numerator=conv.scene.slots.numerator.value;
  var denominator=conv.scene.slots.denominator.value;
  var answer=numerator/denominator;
  answer=answer * 100;
  
  conv.add("You entered " + numerator + " divided by " + denominator + ". Your answer is " + answer + " percent.");
});
```

Comment: nice you could figured out the solution. Could you please accept your own answer so the community can identify the solution to this question?

Comment: I can't accept it yet. I need to go 20 more hours before it will let me do that.